# executing custom commands on server remotely c windows

Tags: c, linux, windows

I have made a Linux fileserver and a windows client in C. I would like to be able to execute commands via the client on the server. For example I want the server to execute the 'ls' command and send back the results. I know that the server can execute ls with execl(), but what I'm interested in is how to let the server know what command to execute.

Input example (client):

ls server

Output example (results send by server):

mail.c public.html test.txt docu.php

Any code would be helpful, but some form of explanation will do fine.

Comment: Have you heard of `sockets`? If not, I suggest you learn about them!

Comment: Telnet to the server?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this might be to setup a small web services API on the Linux host, so that this can be done over http(s).  If you are running apache and PHP on the Linux host, the Windows client can simply post the commands to the PHP script, then the PHP script can run the commands (by way of the shell_exec function), and echo the results back to the Windows client.  But, whenever you are doing something like this, you need to think defensively, because there are many attack vectors with things like this.  Be sure that you put a check in the PHP script to make sure the commands are safe.  And, if possible restrict connections to only the Windows client.